# When signing into Magento admin, it initially allows me to sign in, but when I click any link in the admin, it boots me out. Why?

Tags: magento

Basically whenever I try to login to the Magento admin, it initially works fine, but as soon as I click on a link, it boots me out.  When I log back in, everything works fine.

There's also some weird behavior in that I have to clear the cache anytime I need to run a sales report (or any other report.)

Answer (score 0):

what is your admin url?  Magento doesnt like things like "localhost" if your not setting up a www.website.com then it will cause problems with your admin access it will let you log-in but not actually access the information.  If your creating a test environment i suggest you use the ip address as the url. I hope that helps